# Summing elements between two NAs

Tags: r

I have a dataset which has the following form:

```
  > dput(greece_news_data_combined[27192:27220,])
structure(list(time_and_date_correct = structure(c(1295435821.228, 
1295436780, 1295436780, 1295441160, 1295449020, 1295449020, 1295449020, 
1295449020, 1295449020, 1295449020, 1295449020, 1295449020, 1295462160, 
1295462160, 1295464200, 1295464200, 1295497810.833, 1295498110.378, 
1295498410.519, 1295498710.444, 1295499010.456, 1295499310.399, 
1295499610.479, 1295499910.325, 1295500210.583, 1295500510.338, 
1295500810.38, 1295501110.317, 1295501410.539), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), log_returns = c(0, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -0.00601513577729679, 
-0.000206914274819529, 2.67010219832664e-05, 0.0024201544576403, 
0.0050083466252285, -0.00333167721488612, 0.00130213542003227, 
0.00560767076743004, 0.000679785002929741, 0.000336421598800745, 
-7.91478416137673e-05, 0.00181223339755887, 0.00268922532925481
), negative_percentage = c(NA, 2.20883534136546, 2.20883534136546, 
5.55555555555556, 3.59897172236504, 3.59897172236504, 3.59897172236504, 
3.59897172236504, 3.59897172236504, 3.59897172236504, 3.59897172236504, 
3.59897172236504, 4.45269016697588, 4.45269016697588, 1.39442231075697, 
2.1978021978022, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), positive_percentage = c(NA, 2.81124497991968, 2.81124497991968, 
3.17460317460317, 0.25706940874036, 0.25706940874036, 0.25706940874036, 
0.25706940874036, 0.25706940874036, 0.25706940874036, 0.25706940874036, 
0.25706940874036, 0.556586270871985, 0.556586270871985, 0.99601593625498, 
1.0989010989011, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), sum_of_negative = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), number_of_articles = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
)), row.names = 27192:27220, class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to keep the sums of the rows between the NAs, as well as how many these are. There are multiple parts of my dataset which appear between NAs, I would like to somehow collapse them and then have the sums and the number of lines so that I can compute the averages for the Variables Var1 etc. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Please give a [mcve] in your question! What have you tried so far? What is the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

The following should yield what you're after.  function naSplits() identifies where NA values occur before/after a non-NA value, returning the position index of the NA/non-NA breaks by which to segment the sets.  For NA values on the margins (or lack thereof) either a starting index of 1 or the length of the vector is appended to give start-end position pairsets as a vector.  This is then split into a list of start/end position pairs that are iterated over.  lapply is used to iterate across your columns by creating a data.frame called df_splits from the df defined in your example.  The result is a list of intermediate sequences of non-NA values, a count of their length and a sum of their values.

```
naSplits <- function(vec)
{
  naBelow <- is.na(vec[c(2:length(vec),length(vec))])
  naAbove <- is.na(vec[c(1,1:length(vec)-1)])
  naRow <- is.na(vec)

  splits <- which((!naRow & naAbove) | (!naRow & naBelow))

  if (!is.na(vec[1])) splits <- c(1,splits)
  if (!is.na(vec[length(vec)])) splits <- c(splits,length(vec))

  split_groups <- cumsum(seq_along(splits) %% 2)
  split(data.frame(split_groups,splits,type=c("start","end")),split_groups)
}


df_splits <- df[,c("log_returns","negative_percentage","positive_percentage")]
lapply(df_splits,function(xA) {
  splits <- naSplits(xA)
  lapply(splits,function(xB) {
    start <- xB$splits[xB$type=="start"]
    end <- xB$splits[xB$type=="end"]
    values <- xA[start:end]
    list(values=list(values),count=length(values),total=sum(values))
  })
})
```

The output gives what seems requested in your question:

```
$log_returns
$log_returns$`1`
$log_returns$`1`$values
$log_returns$`1`$values[[1]]
[1] 0
$log_returns$`1`$count
[1] 1
$log_returns$`1`$total
[1] 0 

$log_returns$`2`
$log_returns$`2`$values
$log_returns$`2`$values[[1]]
 [1] -6.015136e-03 -2.069143e-04  2.670102e-05  2.420154e-03  5.008347e-03 -3.331677e-03  1.302135e-03  5.607671e-03  6.797850e-04  3.364216e-04 -7.914784e-05  1.812233e-03
[13]  2.689225e-03
$log_returns$`2`$count
[1] 13    
$log_returns$`2`$total
[1] 0.0102498

$negative_percentage
$negative_percentage$`1`
$negative_percentage$`1`$values
$negative_percentage$`1`$values[[1]]
 [1] 2.208835 2.208835 5.555556 3.598972 3.598972 3.598972 3.598972 3.598972 3.598972 3.598972 3.598972 4.452690 4.452690 1.394422 2.197802
$negative_percentage$`1`$count
[1] 15
$negative_percentage$`1`$total
[1] 51.2626

$positive_percentage
$positive_percentage$`1`
$positive_percentage$`1`$values
$positive_percentage$`1`$values[[1]]
 [1] 2.8112450 2.8112450 3.1746032 0.2570694 0.2570694 0.2570694 0.2570694 0.2570694 0.2570694 0.2570694 0.2570694 0.5565863 0.5565863 0.9960159 1.0989011
$positive_percentage$`1`$count
[1] 15
$positive_percentage$`1`$total
[1] 14.06174
```

Comment: Seems like what you are doing is getting one average for all non NAs and all NAs? I want to calculate it for all time points between NAs. I.e. let's suppose I have a dataset `NA val1 val2 NA val3 val4 NA` I would like to calculate this separately. And keep one row between the first two NAs and one row between the second pair of NAs. I want this to be done for all NA intervals in my dataset.. Hope this helps

Comment: For a set, there is only one average for that set.  Does your question seek rather to segment a column into many separate sets, separated by 1 (or more) NA values?  If yes, Is there any relationship to adjacent columns (eg, NAs across all rows) or is it just the set(s) within each column that are separated by NAs?  And what of the time column?  Your var1 column, would return two averages, 0 and also -0.004767551, since these are the two sets that are separated by NA values in between?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to get one row with the sums and the number of elements for every pair of NAs. A column that initially looks like `NA val1 val2 NA val3 val4 val5 NA` will afterwards be `NA val6 NA val7 NA` where in the rows where `val6` and `val7` are I will have the sums of `val1 and val2` and `val3 and val4 and val5` as well as the number of the elements we collapsed (in this case 2 and 3 respectively)

Comment: Revised answer according to the updated specifications of the question.